# Setting up a call to external js class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

It may be a simple question, but being a newbie it is hard to get it to run.

So I have this leanModal javascript class, which I want to use for a modal popup.

here is the example paragraph that has to appear once an image is clicked:

```
<p id="lean_overlay"> Some text to appear</p>
```

Following is the css that is applied to it:

```
#lean_overlay {
    position: fixed;
    z-index:100;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    background: #000;
    display: none;
}
```

The tutorial of leanModal class says the following:

*Step 3: call the function on your modal trigger, as follows. Be sure to set the href attribute of your trigger anchor to match the id of your target element.*

```
$("#trigger_id").leanModal();
```

What I want to be done is once an img is clicked, the leanModal method to be called, but I got lost in the previous tutorial, in particular which element is a modal trigger and which one is the target element. Moreover, how to call a function once an image is clicked?

any help is much appreciated.

Comment: can you paste the link for the tutorial, it seems you've missed a crucial part where that leanModal() function is attached.

Comment: Here is the tutorial: [link](http://leanmodal.finelysliced.com.au)
I have downloaded the script and included it properly: `<script type="text/javascript" src="leanModal/jquery.leanModal.min.js"></script>`

The question is how to call it when an image is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned image is clicked, then you can check its target by

```
$('img').click(function (e) {
alert(e.target);
});
```